# Can't give parameter values to extension method UIAlertController

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I am trying to write an extension method that generates an UIAlertController based on what you give as a parameter.

```
extension UIAlertController {
   func generate(messageText: String, messageTitle: String, buttonText: String) {
       let alert = UIAlertController(title: messageTitle, message: messageText, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
       alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
       self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

This doesn't give an error.

But when I try to call it and add the parameter values

```
var alertTest = UIAlertController.generate("")
```

It gives the following error:  `Type 'UIAlertController' does not conform to protocol 'StringLiteralConvertible'`

How can I fix this?

Or isn't it possible what i am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some differences between how you have defined the `generate` method in the extension and how you are using it.

`generate` is declared as a function accepting 3 string parameters and returning void.

You are calling as a static method instead, passing one parameter, and expecting a return value.

The right way of using it is like this:

```
var alert = UIAlertController()
alert.generate("A Message", messageTitle: "A title", buttonText: "A button label")
```

However I think that the method implementation is incorrect, because you are creating a new instance of `UIAlertController` instead of (re)using the one the method is called on. What you probably need is a static method, in which case it should look like:

```
extension UIAlertController {
    class func generate(# parent: UIViewController, messageText: String, messageTitle: String, buttonText: String) -> UIAlertController {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: messageTitle, message: messageText, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        parent.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return alert
    }
}
```

and used as:

```
var alert = UIAlertController.generate(parent: self, messageText: "A Message", messageTitle: "A title", buttonText: "A button label")
```

Comment: Thanks this makes sence:)